# Lua implementation of a text-based spreadsheets editor

Tags: lua

> **Disclaimer:** While the code in this question looks extremely long, I'm really only interested in reviewing some small parts of it. While I would sure appreciate someone going crazy and reviewing it entirely, this is certainly not needed. I included the full code so it can be run and tested.

I've been studying [lua](/questions/tagged/lua) for quite some time now (more than I'd like to admit, given that I'm still not that good), but I never quite got to make production quality code. I'd like to change that soon, so I'm practicing by making some projects just for fun, and trying to use as much good practices as I could read about (and remmember).

**About the project:** This is a simple console-based spreadsheets editor (think *Excel/Calc/Gnumeric*), made abusing lua's interactive mode (`lua -i file.lua`). In the end of the file there's an example on how to use. Simply throw in some lua functions to edit the spreadsheet and navigate. To update the cells and print the sheet, use `step()`. You can pass a number to `step()` to make that many steps (and only print once).

**About the review:** The function I'm most interested in is `print_sheet`. Lua is famous for being great at string manipulation, so I'm sure all this boilerplate code is not needed, and its readability sucks (sorry about that). The best way to know what it's doing is just running in interactive mode and calling `step()`. You may want to adjust the size of your terminal, or use the function `columns_visible(value)` to adjust the printed table, as the program doesn't know your terminal size and may print a mess if total column size is larger than it' width. You may also want to experiment with the viewport using functions `next_page()`, `previous_page()`, `rows_visible(value)`, or `viewport(row,column)`. `drag()` and the metatables I'm also interested in, but let's make them optional :).

### Some useful functions:

- `new_sheet(string)`: Creates a new sheet with the name passed.
- `switch(string)`: Edit the sheet with the name passed.
- `drop()`: Deletes the current sheet.
- `sheets()`: List all sheets.
- `next_page()`: Show the next batch of rows.
- `previous_page()`: Show the previous batch of rows.
- `stretch_to_fit(first_column, last_column)`: adjust the size of the column(s) to fit their content.
- `header(value)` sets the header size to the provided value. Rows from 1 to this value will always be shown, regardless of the viewport.
- `step(optional_value)`: updates all cells, and print the current viewport. Passing a value will case the program to do that many steps.
- `update_all()`: Same as `step()`, but does not print.
- `print_sheet`: Prints the sheet, without updating.
- `buffered_update(bool):` sets update mode to buffered or unbuffered. This has implications when the sheet has circular references. Buffered mode(the default) also increases the number of steps needed (you may want to call `step(20)` instead of just `step()`) for a meaningful update, so it's somewhat slower, but is generally more stable.
- `drag(row,column,direction,steps,optional_extension)`: Will copy the contents/formula of the cell specified by row/column the provided number of cells in the provided direction. The direction may be `"up"`, `"down"`, `"left"` or `"right"`. The optional extension makes it possible to do multiple drags in the same direction. Suppose I call `drag(1,1,"down",3,2)`: Since I'm dragging down, the extension means I also want to drag 2 cells to the right, so it will drag cells (1,1), (1,2) and (1,3) 3 cells down.
- `hfill(row, column, ...)`: Horizontal fill. Starting at (row,column) and going right, sets each cell to the next value provided. nil values will be skipped.
- `vfill(row, column, ...)`: Vertical fill. Same as `hfill`, but it moves *down*.
- `seq_vfind()`: Similar functionality as excel's VLOOKUP. Useful for formulas. Read the comment above it in the code for more info.
- `seq_hfind()`: Same as `seq_vfind()`, but searches horizontally.

Without furter ado, here it is:

```
-- before reading this code, please consider the following idioms:
---- variables "r" and "c" always refer to a row and a column.
------ this is specially important in formula functions,
------ as they always must accept a parameter for the row and column.
---- a formula is a lua function registered in the formula_bodies table.
---- most functions meant to be used in formulas accept r,c as first parameters

-- this weak table is meant to enable easy saving of the spreadsheets later.
formula_bodies_mt = {
  __mode = "k"
}
formula_bodies = {}
setmetatable(formula_bodies, formula_bodies_mt)

-- formulas must meet some criteria, the main one being that it must have their
-- body registered as a string in the formula_bodies table (so it can later be
-- saved to a file). This means a formula must always be created using a string,
-- but it can later be copied as a function, when needed.
formula_mt = {
  __newindex = function(t,j,v)
    if type(v) == "string" then
      str =  "func_tmp = function(r,c) " .. v .. " end"
      local f = loadstring(str)
      f()
      if func_tmp == nil then
        error("Syntax error on formula.",2)
      end
      t.func[j] = func_tmp
      t.cell_row[j] = ""
      formula_bodies[func_tmp] = v
      func_tmp = nil
      return
    end
    if type(v) == "function" then
      if formula_bodies[v] == nil then
        error("Function assigned for cell is not a formula.",2)
      end
      t.func[j] = v
      t.cell_row[j] = ""
      return
    end
    if v == nil then
      t.func[j] = nil
      return
    end
    error("Invalid assignment for formula. Type must be a string or a function.",2)
  end,
  __index = function(t,j)
    return t.func[j]
  end,
}

-- this is the metatable for both the formulas and cells "rows tables"
mt = {
  __index = function(t,i)
    t[i] = {}
    if t.is_formula_table then
      t[i].func = {cell_row = t.cells[i]}
      setmetatable(t[i], formula_mt)
      if t.cells[i] == nil then
        t.cells[i] = {}
      end
    else
      t[i]["r"] = i
    end
    return t[i]
  end
}

-- this table is used for buffered update (more details a couple lines below)
local new = {is_formula_table = false} setmetatable(new,mt)
local _sheets = {}

-- by default, column size is 10 characters
local colsize_mt = {
  __index = function()
    return 10
  end
}

-- by default, all rows are visible
local viewrow_mt = {
  __index = function()
    return true
  end
}

-- makes the provided column have the minimum size needed to show its content.
local stretch_to_fit_ = function(c)
  colsize[c] = 0
  for i,v in pairs(cell) do
    if type(v) == "table" and v[c] and #tostring(v[c]) > colsize[c] then
      colsize[c] = #tostring(v[c])
    end
  end
end

function stretch_to_fit(s,e)
  if e == nil then e = s end
  for i=s,e do
    stretch_to_fit_(i)
  end
end

-- creates a sheet and switches to it.
function new_sheet(name)
  cell      = {is_formula_table = false}              setmetatable(cell,mt) 
  formula   = {is_formula_table = true, cells = cell} setmetatable(formula,mt)
  colsize   = {}                                      setmetatable(colsize,colsize_mt)
  view_row  = {}                                      setmetatable(view_row,viewrow_mt)
  info = {
    viewport = {c = 1, r = 1},
    rows_visible = 10,
    columns_visible = 10,
    header = 0,
    margin = 0,
  }
  _sheets[name] = {
    formula_  = formula,
    cell_     = cell,
    colsize_  = colsize,
    view_row_ = view_row,
    info_     = info,
  }
  current_sheet = name
  step()
end

-- drops current sheet
function drop()
  if current_sheet == "" then
    error("No sheet selected.",2)
  end
  formula = nil
  cell = nil
  local s = _sheets[current_sheet]
  s.formula_ = nil
  s.cell_    = nil
  _sheets[current_sheet] = nil
  current_sheet = ""
  for k in pairs(_sheets) do
    switch(k)
    return true
  end
end

-- list all sheets
function sheets()
  for k in pairs(_sheets) do print(k) end
end

-- changes current sheet
function switch(sheet)
  local s = _sheets[sheet]
  if type(s) == "table" and s.formula_ and s.cell_ then
    formula  = s.formula_
    cell     = s.cell_
    colsize  = s.colsize_
    view_row = s.view_row_
    info     = s.info_
    current_sheet = sheet
    step()
    return true
  end
  error("Sheet does not exist.",2)
end

local err_mt = {
  __tostring = function()
    return "#ERR#"
  end
}

-- make an "exception table" and returns it.
function make_formula_error(val)
  local formula_error = {str = val}
  setmetatable(formula_error,err_mt)
  return formula_error
end

function update_all()
  if current_sheet == "" then
    error("No sheet selected.",2)
  end
  for row_index,row in pairs(cell) do
    if type(row) == "table" then
      for column_index in pairs(row) do
        local func = formula[row_index][column_index]
        if func then
          local ok, val = pcall(func, row_index, column_index)
          if ok then
            new[row_index][column_index] = val
          else
            new[row_index][column_index] = make_formula_error(val)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
  for row_index,row in pairs(cell) do
    if type(row) == "table" then
      for column_index in pairs(row) do
        local func = formula[row_index][column_index]
        if func then
          cell[row_index][column_index] = new[row_index][column_index]
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return true
end

-- The default behavior is to buffer the updated values before, which allows for
-- more consistent behavior for circular dependencies, but it's slower. An
-- unbufered, faster option is provided should the user need it.
local buffered_update_ = {
  [true]  = update_all,
  [false] = function()
    if current_sheet == "" then
      error("No sheet selected.",2)
    end
    for row_index,row in pairs(cell) do
      if type(row) == "table" then
        for column_index in pairs(row) do
          local func = formula[row_index][column_index]
          if func then
            local ok, val = pcall(func, row_index, column_index)
            if ok then
              cell[row_index][column_index] = val
            else
              cell[row_index][column_index] = make_formula_error(val)
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
    return true
  end
}

-- switches the update mode from buffered(true) to unbufered(false)
function buffered_update(option)
  update_all = buffered_update_[option]
end

header = function(n)
  info.header = n
end

-- sets the first row and column that is visible on the terminal.
viewport = function(r,c)
  local r_s = 99999999999999 - info.rows_visible + 1
  local c_s = 99999999999999 - info.columns_visible + info.header + 1
  r = r < r_s and r or r_s
  c = c < c_s and c or c_s
  info.viewport.r = r > 0 and r or 1
  info.viewport.c = c > 0 and c or 1
end

-- sets the number of rows that are visible
rows_visible = function(val)
  info.rows_visible = val
  viewport(info.viewport.r,info.viewport.c)
end

-- sets the number of columns that are visible
columns_visible = function(val)
  info.columns_visible = val
  viewport(info.viewport.r,info.viewport.c)
end

-- advances `rows_visible` rows on the viewport
next_page = function()
  viewport(info.viewport.r + info.rows_visible - info.header,info.viewport.c)
  print_sheet()
end

-- go back `rows_visible` rows on the viewport
previous_page = function()
  viewport(info.viewport.r - info.rows_visible + info.header,info.viewport.c)
  print_sheet()
end

-- This big, cumbersome function, that needs a lot of refactoring, prints the
-- sheet according to the current viewport.
function print_sheet()
  local r = info.viewport.r
  local c = info.viewport.c
  local e = info.columns_visible-1
  local first_col_size = #tostring(r+info.rows_visible-1)+2
  if current_sheet == "" then
    error("No sheet selected.",2)
  end
  print('Sheet "' .. current_sheet .. '":')
  local i = c
  io.write(string.rep(" ",first_col_size))
  while i <= (c+e) do
    local str = tostring(i)
    local fill_size = colsize[i]-#str
    if #str > colsize[i] then
      if colsize[i] > 1 then
        str = "<" .. string.sub(str,-colsize[i]+1,-1)
      else
        str = string.rep("<",colsize[i]-1)
      end
    end
    if colsize[i] > 0 then
      io.write("{" .. string.rep(" ",fill_size) .. str .. "}")
    else
      e = e+1
    end
    i = i+1
  end
  io.write("\n")
  -- I define a function to avoid code duplication below.
  print_row = function(tb)
    if view_row[tb.i] then
      c_size = first_col_size-#tostring(tb.i)-2
      io.write("{" .. string.rep(" ",c_size) .. tb.i .. "}")
      if cell[tb.i] then
        for j = c,(c+e) do
          if colsize[j] > 0 then
            io.write("[")
            local val = tostring(cell[tb.i][j])
            local str
            if #val > colsize[j] then
              str = string.sub(tostring(cell[tb.i][j]),1,colsize[j]-1) .. ">"
            else
              str = val
            end
            local fill_size = colsize[j] - #str
            if cell[tb.i][j] then
              if type(cell[tb.i][j]) ~= "number" then
                io.write(str .. string.rep(" ",fill_size))
              else
                io.write(string.rep(" ",fill_size) .. str)
              end
            else
              io.write(string.rep(" ",colsize[j]))
            end
            io.write("]")
          end
        end
      else
        for j = 1,info.columns_visible do io.write("[" .. string.rep(" ",colsize[j]) .. "]") end
      end
      io.write("\n")
    else
      tb.total = tb.total + 1
    end
    tb.i = tb.i+1
  end
  -- I only use a table here so I can "pass by reference". Is this a bad idea?
  local tb = {
    i = 1,
    total = info.header,
  }
  while tb.i <= tb.total do -- print header rows.
    print_row(tb)
  end
  tb = {
    i = r > info.header and r or info.header+1,
    total = r+info.rows_visible-1-info.header,
  }
  while tb.i <= tb.total do -- print visible rows.
    print_row(tb)
  end
  return true
end

-- updates all cells and prints the current sheet.
function step(n)
  if current_sheet == "" then
    error("No sheet selected.",2)
  end
  if n == nil then n = 1 end
  for i=1,n do
    update_all()
  end
  print_sheet()
  return true
end

-- returns the value of the cell
function getcell(sheet,r,c)
  return _sheets[sheet].cell_[r][c]
end

-- an error in a cell is displayed as #ERR#. This function can get the string for it.
function geterror(r,c)
  return cell[r][c].str
end

-- returns the formula string of the cell
function getformula(r,c)
  return formula_bodies[formula[r][c]]
end

-- I would really love to avoid the duplication here.
function drag(r,c,direction,n,e)
  if e == nil then e = 1 end
  if direction == "right" then
    for k = r,(r+e-1) do
      for i=(c+1),(c+n) do
        cell[k][i] = cell[k][c]
        formula[k][i] = formula[k][c]
      end
    end
    return
  end
  if direction == "left" then
    for k = r,(r+e-1) do
      for i=(c-1),(c-n),-1 do
        cell[k][i] = cell[k][c]
        formula[k][i] = formula[k][c]
      end
    end
    return
  end
  if direction == "down" then
    for k = c,(c+e-1) do
      for i=(r+1),(r+n) do
        cell[i][k] = cell[r][k]
        formula[i][k] = formula[r][k]
      end
    end
    return
  end
  if direction == "up" then
    for k = c,(c+e-1) do
      for i=(r-1),(r-n) do
        cell[i][k] = cell[r][k]
        formula[i][k] = formula[r][k]
      end
    end
    return
  end
end

-- FUNCTIONS hfill, vfill
-- Will fill the row/column starting at r,c with all parameters, skipping the cell
-- where the parameter is 'nil'
function hfill(r,c,...)
  local params = {...}
  for i,v in pairs(params) do
    cell[r][c+i-1] = v
  end
end

function vfill(r,c,...)
  local params = {...}
  for i,v in pairs(params) do
    cell[r+i-1][c] = v
  end
end

-- FUNCTIONS seq_vfind, seq_hfind
-- Similar functionality to excel VLOOKUP
-- This does a sequential scan and is only useful if the dataset is not ordered.
-- (bin_vfind and bin_hfind are still to be implemented)
-- PARAMETERS:
-- sheet: name of the sheet to search into
-- column: id of the column to search into
-- result: id of the column to extract the value from
-- start: the row to start the search(inclusive)
-- finish: the row to finish the search(inclusive)
-- predicate: the value to search for, or a function that returns
--            true if the value to search for is passed as an argument
function seq_vfind(sheet,column,result,start,finish,predicate)
  if predicate == nil then
    error("seq_vfind: predicate can't be 'nil'",2)
  end
  if type(predicate) ~= "function" then
    local p = predicate
    predicate = function(val)
      return val == p
    end
  end
  local s = _sheets[sheet]
  if s == nil then
    error("seq_vfind: sheet does not exist",2)
  end
  for i=start,finish do
    if predicate(s.cell_[i][column]) then
      return s.cell_[i][result]
    end
  end
  error("seq_vfind: key not found",2)
end

function seq_hfind(sheet,row,result,start,finish,predicate)
  if predicate == nil then
    error("seq_hfind: predicate can't be 'nil'",2)
  end
  if type(predicate) ~= "function" then
    local p = predicate
    predicate = function(val)
      return val == p
    end
  end
  local s = _sheets[sheet]
  if s == nil then
    error("seq_hfind: sheet does not exist",2)
  end
  for i=start,finish do
    if predicate(s.cell_[row][i]) then
      return s.cell_[result][i]
    end
  end
  error("seq_hfind: key not found",2)
end


-- let's create a sample document for demonstration purposes. All of this could be done easily in interactive mode.
new_sheet("students")
hfill(1,1,"registration","name") -- fills the header
-- now let's register some students ...
vfill(2,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15) -- still need a function to make sequences :D
vfill(2,2,"Mary","Luke","Anna","Tony","Bobby Tables","Liz","Scarlet",
          "Cassio","Paul","Nadia","Shosshana","Brad","Lilly","John","Carlos")
step() -- stepping is not really needed since there are no formulas. This will just print the sheet.
-- ... and input the grades for the ones with an odd number
new_sheet("grades")
hfill(1,1,"registration","name","grade 1","grade 2","total","situation")
vfill(2,1,1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15)
formula[2][2] = "return seq_vfind('students',1,2,2,16,cell[r][c-1])" -- look for the student's name in the students sheet.
drag(2,2,"down",8) -- copies the cell[2][2] content(in this case, the formula) though 8 cells below it. the 8th cell is just to showcase the error.
vfill(2,3,2.5,3.2,5.5,.5,6,10,4.1,8.8) -- 1st grades
vfill(2,4,3.2,3,9.5,.2,6.5,10,4.9,7)   -- 2nd grades
formula[2][5] = "return (cell[r][c-2]+cell[r][c-1])/2"
drag(2,5,"down",7)
formula[2][6] = "if cell[r][c-1]<8 then return 'FAILED' else return 'PASSED' end"
drag(2,6,"down",7)
update_all()
formula[10][3] = "return geterror(r,c-1)"
update_all()
stretch_to_fit(1)
stretch_to_fit(2)
stretch_to_fit(3)
header(1) -- size of the header is 1 row. (check effect using next_page())
rows_visible(6)
step()
print("type next_page() to view more, or type rows_visible(11) -- then step() -- to view all rows at once")
```